# Counting frequency of three letter words

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to print out the number of three letter words in a string. The code below outputs the number of 0-3 letter words in a string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input a string:"); 
       String s;
          s = input.nextLine();

     String[] strings = s.split(" ");
     int[] counts = new int[4];
     for(String str : strings)
          if(str.length() < counts.length) counts[str.length()] += 1;
     for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++)
         System.out.println(i + " letter words: " + counts[i]); 

     input.close();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }//end main

}//end class
```

How would I modify this code to only show the number of three letter words? Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this your code? If you've written this, then you should already know how to solve this, no? As an aside, be sure to place all loops and control blocks such as if blocks in curly braces, even if the body is only one line long. At this stage of your programming career doing this will save your tail in the future, trust me.

Comment: It's a modified code of what we've been working on in class. Thanks for the advice, I was taught not to put curly brackets for single line  blocks. But will now implement it!

Comment: The problem is that if you later change a one line if block into two or more lines, but forget to add the curly braces, your logic is hosed. The answer to your question is on your line here `if(str.length() < counts.length) counts[str.length()] += 1;`. Use `==` not `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input a string:"); 
       String s;
          s = input.nextLine();

     String[] strings = s.split(" ");
     int[] counts = new int[4];
     for(String str : strings)
          if(str.length() < counts.length) counts[str.length()] += 1;

     System.out.println(3 + " letter words: " + counts[3]); 

     input.close();

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }//end main

}
```

It might look sth like that,ommited loop `for(int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++)`.